# Can someone help me with Picture in Picture for a HTML5 Player in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webkit

Can anybody tell me how to fix this issue I have with Picture in Picture? I added it for a HTML5 player and took the code from the Apple website, but it's not working for me. It gives me an error saying:

```
 TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'video.webkitSupportsPresentationMode')
(anonymous function)-jquery-3.min.js:2:31697
```

The code:

```
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var PiP = document.getElementById('picture-in-picture');

        // picture-in-picture

        if (video.webkitSupportsPresentationMode && typeof video.webkitSetPresentationMode === "function") {
          // Toggle PiP when the user clicks the button.
          PiP.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            video.webkitSetPresentationMode(video.webkitPresentationMode === "picture-in-picture" ? "inline" : "picture-in-picture");
          });
        } else {
          PiP.disabled = true;
        }
```

I wasn't sure were to place this code. I just put it inside a javascript script tag in the footer.

**Updated:** 
I replaced :

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var PiP = document.getElementById('picture-in-picture');
```

with just:

```
var video = $( "video" );
var PiP = $( "#picture-in-picture" );
```

Inside the jQuery ready and the error is gone but still doesn't work. I put an alert on each of the *if* and *else* condition and it looks like it doesn't even recognize the function.

```
           if (video.webkitSupportsPresentationMode && typeof video.webkitSetPresentationMode === "function") {
              // Toggle PiP when the user clicks the button.
              PiP.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                video.webkitSetPresentationMode(video.webkitPresentationMode === "picture-in-picture" ? "inline" : "picture-in-picture");
              });
                alert("works")
            } else {
              PiP.disabled = true;
                alert("no works") //<--- This is the alert I get
            }
```

i have never tried this PiP until now. Could it be that Apple removed this function in the new Safari? It seems like any html5 video I go to has this option already next to the full screen. But won't be good for a custom HTML5 player which is why I want to add this function to a button.

Comment: Use the debugger (either via a break point or the `debugger` statement and make sure that `video` and `PiP` are not null.  It sounds like these elements do not exist at the time you are calling this code.  EIther they a) Don't exist or b) they doen't exist *yet* and this code is running too early.

Comment: I have the elements above the code. I also tried adding it inside the document ready in jQuery (eg. $(document).ready(function () ) and still the same problem.

Comment: I just used $( "video" ) and $( "#picture-in-picture" ) instead and put inside jquery ready and the error disappeared but still doesn't work. I'll edit the entry to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why the error?

`document.getElementById` returns a DOM object while the jQuery object (created by the `$` method) is a wrapper around a DOM element or a set of DOM. You can [read the detailed explanation here][1].

This mean that if you wanna use jQuery you need to to change:

```
var video = $( "video" );
```

to

```
var video = $( "video" )[0];
```